# How come JavaScript converts to a string when adding a string and a number?

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion

Why is it that this code evaluates to:

```
10 + "10" => "1010"
"10" + 10 => "1010"
```

and why does it *not* work like this:

```
10 + "10" => 20 // the number comes first
"10" + 10 => "1010" // the string comes first
```

EDIT:

More specifically, where in the implementation of the interpreter does it do this? Or, how does it do this?

Comment: Because this is how it is defined in the specification. That's it. *Different* languages may use different rules (but then they are *different* languages).

Comment: Welcome to Javascript. Enjoy your stay.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my eyes because those examples look exactly the same.

Comment: This behavior must be specified in the [ECMA262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)...

Comment: @pst The post was modified since I saw it for first time? I guess it was.

Comment: Also, you can do this `10 + +"10" //=> 20`.

Comment: @istos No, it has not been modified to change the examples.

Comment: @istos I modified the *text* to make it more clear: the code is the same, but the poster is wondering why it *doesn't* work like the "not" case.

Comment: Check out the explanations at the [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.casting) for a  good explanation.

Comment: @pst But at what point does the conversion kick in? I understand it's specified this way - but where/when does it happen in the implementation of the language?

Comment: If you think that's weird, you just gotta see [this video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Comment: Also take this quiz:  http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/

Comment: What's funny is that if it evaluated like the 2nd example, then the question would reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ECMAScript 262 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) codifies the JavaScript language (JavaScript is actually the Mozilla implementation of ECMAScript). In any case, things are relatively easy to find in [Annotated ES5](http://es5.github.com) which I usually consult.

See [11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1):

> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition.
>
> The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. *If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>    Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)*
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the Note below 11.6.3.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is a concatenation operator and as well as arithmetic operator in Javascript. If it finds that operator is used between string and number then it concatenates that number into string else if you using operator for two integers then result will also be integer.

So,

STRING + STRING = STRING

STRING + INTEGER  = STRING

INTEGER + STRING = STRING

INTEGER + INTEGER = INTEGER

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I already understand the rules. I'm more curious as to where in the implementation it makes this cast.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing values that have different types, JavaScript uses a complicated and confusing set of rules.   In general, it just tries to convert one of the values to the type of the other value (as we can see in your question).  This is often noted as automatic type conversion.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
 10 + "10" => "1010"
"10" + 10 => "1010"
```

In JavaScript, if any non-string value is added to a string, the value is automatically converted to a string before it is concatenated. Thus JavaScript, regardless of the ordering of your integer or string values, treats any integer as a string.

You should know, however, that JavaScript does not apply this to all arithmetic operators.  For example, if we were to multiply our values we would get:

```
 10 * "10" => 100
 "10" * 10 => 100
 "ten" * 10 => NaN
```

Now, why does Javascript do this?  Well, you could argue it's for convenience sake.  There are many instances were you might need to concatenate two values into a string.  On the contrary, you can never multiply an integer with a character string, as we can see in the last example above.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this is how Javascript works

Comment: I don't know about the "unfortunately" bit :D

Comment: that means you have to use your brain a bit more rather than relying on the language nature :D